# ng-repeat limit based on the length with ng-if condtion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, limit

```
    <div ng-repeat="badgesData in deptUSersData.badges | limitTo : 7 track by $index">
      ........content.......
    </div>
```

I want to `limitTo : 7` only if `deptUSersData.badges.lenght` is more than 8 how can i do it.?

I want something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="badgesData in deptUSersData.badges 
 ng-if=deptUSersData.badges.lenght > 8 ? limitTo : 7 : '' track by $index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use ng-show with condition checking array length and limit using $index < 7 to limit to 7

```
ng-show="{{deptUSersData.badges.length > 8? $index < 7: true}}">
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vRRQVw

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.limit = 6;
    $scope.deptUSersData = {
       badges :[
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
       ]
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="badgesData in deptUSersData.badges track by $index" ng-show="{{deptUSersData.badges.length > 8? $index < 7: true}}">
      {{badgesData}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Change array length to 8 or less to see the difference

Answer (score 2):

you can set a variable inside the `controller` and use it to limit `ng-repeat`, something like :

```
<div ng-repeat="badgesData in deptUSersData.badges | limitTo : myLimit track by $index">
   ........content.......
</div>


app.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    if(deptUSersData.badges.lenght > 8)
        $scope.myLimit = 7;
  }
);
```

don't worry if `length` is less than `8` and `myLimit` end up being `undefined`

according to : [limitTo documentattion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

> If limit is undefined, the input will be returned unchanged.

so the filter should not apply and  everything should be shown.